# Livewire Component doesn't render when back/forward browser history using Query String

Tags: php, laravel, browser-history

I made a simple full-page component with a simple query string. Component changed successfully when I click the buttons that change the properties, but didn't work when I click back button in browser. I'm using Google Chrome.

Here the detail: https://gifyu.com/image/SIUsh

Controller

```
class LivewireTest extends Component
{
    public $activeMenu = '';

    protected $queryString = [
        'activeMenu' => ['except' => '', 'as' => 'type'],
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('testbaru::livewire-test')->layout('testbaru::livewire-layout');
    }

    public function ChangeMenu($menu)
    {
        $this->activeMenu = $menu;
    }
}
```

Component `livewire-test.blade.php`

```
<div>
    <div wire:key="{{ $this->activeMenu }}">
        <div wire:loading>
            Loading ...
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" wire:click="ChangeMenu('home')">Menu</button>
        <button type="button" wire:click="ChangeMenu('profile')">Profile</button>
        <br>
        @if ($activeMenu == "home")
            Home Active
        @else
            Profile Active
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Layout `livewire-layout.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Welcome!
        <br>
        <br>
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>

    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

Am I doing wrong? Or this is a bug?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm also finding that the queryString prop will sometimes cause the back button to go to the previous state, even when then URI has not been changed.

Try removing the query string and see if that affects the behaviour.

Edit: said prop was an array, adding `'except' => []` fixed it for me.